# Automorphism on graphs which isn't isomorphic?

Tags: graph-theory

So I got the following graph and the Task to determine the Elements of it's automorphism group. The Automorphism is defined as a Graph that is isomorphic to itself. But I think the given Graph isn't isomorphic, so there can't be any Elements in its automorphism group:

[image]

Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 4):

The degree one vertex must not be moved. Thus its neighbor must not be moved. This vertex's other neighbors are of differing degree and thus cannot be moved. Similarly the remaining two vertices cannot be moved.

Put otherwise we have no non-trivial automorphisms with respect to the topological structure and thus have no candidates for automorphisms on the (more restricted) graph structure.

Answer (score 3):

An isomorphism is a map between two relational structures that is a bijection and preserves the relations. In algebra, the relations are the operators. In graph theory, we are dealing with the adjacency relation. So the identity map is an automorphism. More so, the isomorphism relation is an equivalence relation, meaning it is reflexive.

So your job is to determine the automorphisms for this graph. Some hints- automorphism preserves both the neighborhood set and vertex degree. It also preserves the distance metric (which is the shortest path metric).

Comment: So, the identity is the only automorphism of my graph? And, is there a Graph with an automorphism group which only consits of Isomorphisms? Sorry, a question that popped up in my head as I was reading your comment.

Comment: Automorphisms *are* isomorphisms; every automorphism group will contain only isomorphisms.

Comment: A graph isomorphism is a function $\phi : V(G) \to V(H)$ that is a bijection and satisfies $ij \in E(G) \implies \phi(i)\phi(j) \in E(H)$. When $G$ and $H$ are the same graph, we call the isomorphism an automorphism. The isomorphism relation asks if two graphs are the same up to relabeling. The automorphism question asks in how many ways a graph is isomorphic to itself.